# WebLogic 12c Migration issue with Unmarshalling JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling, weblogic12c

We have an application running currently on WebLogic 10.3.5.0 and we are migrating to WL 12.1.2.0.0. We are experiencing issues with Un-marshalling WS calls to another application. We're familiar with the *Marshalling* bug when upgrading, however it seems this issue is not the same.

Something weird to note is that it works fine on DEV/Test servers of the same WL version, but will return the following error when deployed locally (must be a env/configuration setting mismatch?):

```
JAXB unmarshalling exception: null; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException - with linked exception: [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'xsi:nil' is not allowed to appear in element 'error'.]
```

From the error message, it seems that it's not recognizing the xsi namespace or something. The schema has not changed from 10.3.5, and shouldn't be the root of the issue. Anyone have any ideas or even a starting place to look?

Many thanks

Edit: Adding web.xml and weblogic.xml

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="cpc-mi" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
...
</web-app>
```

weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd 
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app 
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd" 
    xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
...
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Comment: Yes, there are schema differences between 10.3 and 12c. What does your `weblogic-application.xml` etc look like? Do not include any references to `bea.com`

Comment: We do not have a `weblogic-application.xml`. Could that be part of the issue?

Comment: We struggled with some of the header information in our web.xml, weblogic-application.xml, etc files. Can you post the contents of your app xml files?

Comment: I've edited the OP to include our web and weblogic.xml headers (excluding the application specifics). Maybe we're getting somewhere here, do the namespaces look right? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebLogic 12c (WLS 12c) has its own jar libraries including and jaxb. I already work with this server, and when I want to use JSF (another library that WebLogic comes with) I have to tell WLS 12c that ignore its own JSF libraries and use mine, included in war/ear.

You can use `weblogic.xml` descriptor inside `WEB-INF` folder to achieve this. Here you are with one of my `weblogic.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">

  <container-descriptor>
    <prefer-application-packages> 
      <package-name>javax.faces.*</package-name> 
      <package-name>com.sun.faces.*</package-name> 
      <package-name>com.bea.faces.*</package-name> 
      <package-name>org.apache.commons.io.*</package-name>
      <package-name>org.apache.commons.fileupload.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages> 

    <prefer-application-resources> 
      <resource-name>javax.faces.*</resource-name> 
      <resource-name>com.sun.faces.*</resource-name> 
      <resource-name>com.bea.faces.*</resource-name> 
      <resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer</resource-name>
      <resource-name>META-INF/services/com.sun.faces.*</resource-name>
    </prefer-application-resources>

    <show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</show-archived-real-path-enabled>
  </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Of course you include your own jaxb dependency into your war/ear and tell WLS 12c ignores its jaxb library, using `java.xml.bind.*` value for `package-name` tag and maybe also for the `resource-name` tag.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think this might be the issue. We happen to be using `org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller`. Would you happen to know exactly how to add it here? I've tried adding variables of the class name under application packages, but it doesn't seem to be having an effect. Thanks!

Comment: Well I think I got wrong. I have just used jarscan to search into WLS libraries (`/opt/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib`) and I didn't found Jaxb2Marshaller. Then I searched for what jaxb classes are included into WLS and only found three that are not related with your problem, so I think my answer is not related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know very little about this and I'm not sure if this is even remotely correct, but does putting xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" in the XML instance make it work?

Comment: Is is in the XML response already. `<error xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>`

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue:  Parsing of soap messages was working in 10.3.x, but failing in 12.x. The issue turned out to be an outdated xercesImpl.jar.  I doubt that this is what's going on with you, but I thought I share the experience just in case.

NOte that the outdated xercesImpl.jar was included in one of our war files deployed as a library, NOT anything shipped by Oracle as part of WebLogic 12